# Is iOS programming going virtual with Clang and llvm?

Tags: ios, compiler-construction, virtual, llvm, clang

I dont understand the whole Clang and llvm thingy. I asked myself if the code is running in a VM while runtime on the iOS device or wether it is going through a "VM" while compile time, for compile-time optimization and so on?

Comment: 'VM' in 'LLVM' is not what you think. It is an intermediate abstract machine representation, just the same as in gcc and virtually any other compiler out there. So many people had been fooled by this name - nice trolling, LLVM team!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LLVM is not a virtual machine in *that* sense of the word. The thing is that LLVM is a code generator that helps unifying compilers, languages and target processors/OSes. LLVM is useful for compiler developers only. In fact, in the Clang compiler, it plays a major role, but that's entirely internal - what comes out of Clang is pure, native ARM/iOS machine code.

Comment: Wrong. LLVM *is* a compiler. It compiles a high level language (LLVM IR) into native code for a variety of platforms. Clang, in turn, is a compiler from C/ObjC/C++/OpenCL into LLVM IR. And LLVM is a very useful thing, not just for the compiler developers. One can use it for various code instrumentation, code analysis, arbitrary code transforms, etc.

Comment: @SK-logic fixed the first part - but "One can use it for various code instrumentation, code analysis, arbitrary code transforms, etc" - well, compiler developers do that, right?

Comment: no, you don't have to be a compiler developer in order to be interested, in, say, a semantic search in your code base. In one occasion, for example, I've used LLVM IR for locating all the places where a data returned from a certain function had been implicitly casted to `double`. It is also very useful for generating call graphs and other useful data for code study.

Comment: @SK-logic yes, that's right of course! But still, it's rather close to compiler development, language analysis and things like that - not something that would interest someone who doesn't even know what LLVM is.

Comment: thanks a lot you two ;), I was wondering because I do not really like the trend to JIT-langs like java.

Comment: @sh4kesbeer don't worry, Apple isn't as supid as Google (who basically messed up their platform by making a slow crap [Java] as the official langauge of Android... Interpreted language for mobile development? Gooogle, are you just kidding me?)

Comment: thats exactly my opinion of android! Samsung makes S3, oohh quad core pretty cool, must have a good performance. Then when testing it: Wtf, quad core and the springboard (or what it is called in android) is still laggy...

Comment: @sh4kesbeer yeah... And they're blaming us C programmers to be low-level and outdated... Sure thing...

Comment: @sh4kesbeer, Android is so laggy and shaky because Google coders are incapable of thinking asynchronously. Some form of a "learning difficulty" (to put it PC way), I suppose. VM performance does not matter much for most of those tasks (anyway, all the rendering is native there). You can get a smooth, nice, soft realtime responsiveness in a purely interpreted environment - see Erlang for example. And highly optimised native code can behave really badly, because of a lack of asynchronous real time UI.

Comment: @SK-logic and so on... Yes, you're right in most of what you mean. But interpreting will never bring the same perormance as optimized native code. Never. Ever.

Comment: @H2CO3, of course. But, there is not such a strong correlation between UI responsiveness and a sequential code performance. Tcl/Tk UI can often be much faster and smoother than a badly written Qt or GTK or MFC app.

Comment: @SK-Logic there's no much sense in comparing a well-written and a badly-written program. Also, I really believe that there's a very strong correlation between UI responsiveness and the actual code. Graphics processing is among the most computationally expensive operations.

Comment: @H2CO3, only the rendering is expensive. And nowadays it is done mostly by hardware anyway. CPU is idle all the time. GUI is not nearly a computationally intensive stuff.